# Factory Method pattern to avoid instantiation of objects based on conditional logics

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

In a scenario like below where an object needs to be intantiated based on some conditional logic, can the **factory method pattern** help to avoid client code getting cluttered due to number of if/elseif conditions (which would also be a maintenance nightmare if more and more products needs to get created due to different variations of logics).

Or else is there a any other design pattern that could come to rescue?

```
public interface IProduct
{
    void Method1();
}

public class ProductA : IProduct
{
    void Method1()
    {
    }
}

public class ProductB : IProduct
{
    void Method1()
    {
    }
}

public class ProductC : IProduct
{
    void Method1()
    {
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public void Test()
    {
        int count = 5;

        IProduct product;

        if (count < 10)
        {
            product = new ProductA();
        }
        else if (count == 10)
        {
            product = new ProductB();
        }
        else if (count > 10)
        {
            product = new ProductC();
        }

        product.Method1();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the factory pattern is exactly what you want:

```
public class ProductFactory
{
    public IProduct GetProduct(int count)
    {
        if (count < 10)
        {
            return new ProductA();
        }
        else if (count == 10)
        {
            return new ProductB();
        }
        else if (count > 10)
        {
            return new ProductC();
        }
    }
}
```

Then wherever your client code needs an instance it can just go

```
public class Client
{
    public void Test()
    {
        ProductFactory factory = new ProductFactory();

        IProduct product = factory.GetProduct(5);

        product.Method1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe Mr. Carver's solution strictly follows the structure of the Factory Pattern described in the GOF Design Pattern book . However, it is a very common programming idiom (Simple Factory) and likely a good approach for this design.

The Factory Pattern calls for the Concrete Creator to be derived from a Creator.  Typically, the Creator delegates the creation of the product to the Concrete Creator.  This is useful when a new factory might be added in the future.  For example, imagine if you created a new factory that could manufacture a the specific products with less resources (count is used as a proxy for "resource").

```
    public interface IProduct
    {
      void PerformService();
    }

    public class ProductA : IProduct
    {
      public void PerformService()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Product A's service.");
      }
    }

    public class ProductB : IProduct
    {
      public void PerformService()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Product B's service.");
      }
    }

    public class ProductC : IProduct
    {
      public void PerformService()
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Product C's service.");
      }
    }

    abstract class ProductFactory
    {
      public abstract IProduct CreateProduct(int count);
    }

    class OriginalFactory : ProductFactory
    {
      public override IProduct CreateProduct(int count)
      {
        if (count < 10)
        {
          return new ProductA();
        }
        else if (count == 10)
        {
          return new ProductB();
        }
        else if (count > 10)
        {
          return new ProductC();
        }
        else
        {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }

    class NewFactory : ProductFactory
    {
      public override IProduct CreateProduct(int count)
      {
        if (count < 20)
        {
          return new ProductA();
        }
        else if (count == 20)
        {
          return new ProductB();
        }
        else if (count > 20)
        {
          return new ProductC();
        }
        else
        {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }

    public class FactoryTest
    {
      public void TestNew()
      {
        ProductFactory factory = new NewFactory();
        IProduct product = factory.CreateProduct(10); // Product B
        product.PerformService();
      }
      public void TestOld()
      {
        ProductFactory factory = new OriginalFactory();
        IProduct product = factory.CreateProduct(10); // Product A
        product.PerformService();
      }
    }
```

Comment: How is this different that an abstract factory if i may ask?