# Replace If/Else using polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, polymorphism

I want to remove many if/else conditions from my code. I choose polymorphism to replace it. I have understood the way. I am copying the source I found in Internet.

```
abstract class Bird {
  // ...
  abstract double getSpeed();
}

class European extends Bird {
  double getSpeed() {
    return getBaseSpeed();
  }
}
class African extends Bird {
  double getSpeed() {
    return getBaseSpeed() - getLoadFactor() * numberOfCoconuts;
  }
}
class NorwegianBlue extends Bird {
  double getSpeed() {
    return (isNailed) ? 0 : getBaseSpeed(voltage);
  }
}

// Somewhere in client code
speed = bird.getSpeed();
```

I am ok with it with the above Design.
But my doubt is that if the instantiation of bird object depends on another if/else condition.Then how to solve it ? I am very confused.Please pardon me.It may be very trivial.
e.g

```
if (LocalDateTime.now().getMonth().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("march")) {
    Bird aBird = new European();
} else if (LocalDateTime.now().getMonth().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("August")) {
    Bird aBird = new African();
}
speed = aBird.getSpeed();
```

Please let me know how can I do away with this if/else.

Comment: Much will depend on the requirements of the program, something that we don't know much of at this time.  On an unrelated note, I do have an affinity to your class names for some reason

Comment: Can you please let me know what are the types of  requirements you mean ? We can assume that our requirement is to get speed of the Bird  out of few Birds .But the Bird occur only in certain Months of the Year.. I hope I am ok with requirements

Comment: Since you're creating objects, a factory design pattern comes to mind.

Comment: This one should be helpful ! Thanks ..let me try it out !  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314333/factory-method-pattern-to-avoid-instantiation-of-objects-based-on-conditional-lo

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But in  ground level some if/else shall be there like the example of factory .Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

you must use the if/else because the constructor works only for the implemented class

you can do it a little nicer like this:

```
Bird aBird = null;
String month = LocalDateTime.now().getMonth().toString();
if ("march".equalsIgnoreCase(month)) {
    aBird = new European();
} else if ("August".equalsIgnoreCase(month)) {
    aBird = new African();
}
speed = aBird.getSpeed();
```

implementation of the factory.